# How can I open a image in another tab using Selenium for Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to open picture in another tab while using `selenium`

Ex.: The picture in this article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Bede

Is located here:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Adam_Bede.jpg/220px-Adam_Bede.jpg

Is there any commands or something in `selenium` that can help me?

Comment: What's end the goal here? Maybe you can work your way around that

Answer (score 2):

To do it by going to the wikipedia page first, run:

```
#import libraries
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#open driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#(optional) save window handle
#tab_before = driver.window_handles[0]

#go to wikipedia page
web_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Bede"
driver.get(web_url)

#find image link
im_link = driver.find_element_by_class_name("image")

#open in new tab
im_link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+Keys.RETURN)

#(optional) save new window handle
#tab_after = driver.window_handles[0]

#(optional) switch back to first tab:
#driver.switch_to_window(tab_before)
```

To go there directly, supposing you already have the link, do:

```
##or go directly 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#open web browser
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
im_url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Adam_Bede.jpg/220px-Adam_Bede.jpg"

#open new tab
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')

#go to the link
driver.get(im_url)
```